# Get meeting time when accepting meeting

Tags: c#, outlook

I need to detect a meeting item, for part of an Add In in Outlook.  It gives the user the option to categorise the meeting for their own workload, i.e. project, type etc, nothing trivial.

I am looking at the ItemSend event, using this code

```
Application.ItemSend+=Application_ItemSend;

Outlook.MeetingItem m = (Outlook.MeetingItem)Item;
string s = m.Body;
```

The casting will have error trapping as to not bother the user each time a mail is sent etc.  I've tried a few combinations to get the correct object where I can get .StartTime .EndTime eg from.

However, s is Null, I need to get the meeting time and the meeting body, to shorten as a shortname.

Comment: Use any low-level property explorer tool such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy for viewing hidden and custom properties. I believe there you will find what you need...

Comment: Many thanks.  I shall investigate in case there are any other demands later on :)